# Write applicaton version at the start of every new log file creation

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, log4net

I am using log4net in net 3.5. now what i want is every time my application creates a new log file the version number of the application should be print in the log file.

PS : i know how to get the version number but how to write in log file every time a new log file creates ?

Answer (score 1):

If is possible to define a header in the Layout for your appender:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <header>This is the header</header>
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

The value will be used by the `TextWriterAppender` class (which `FileAppender` and `RollingFileAppender` derive from)

However the header is fixed and doesn't evaluate custom data. The quickest way for you to customize the header would be to implement your own Layout and set the version number in the `Header` property.

```
public class CustomLayout : log4net.Layout.PatternLayout
{
    //inheriting from PatternLayout to minimize changes
    public override string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return "version 1.0.0"; // or however you will retrieve it
        }
        set
        {
            base.Header = value;
        }
    }
}
```

then change your configuration to reference the `CustomLayout` type

```
<layout type="namespace.to.your.CustomLayout">
    <header>This header will be ignored</header>
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

You could even add some formatting into the header property in order to be able to log things such as date, etc